# Angular - application components architecture

Tags: angular

I'm currently experimenting with the design of an application component in `Angular 7.*`. Not having worked a lot with it, I'm finding it hard to design a clean components architecture.

This component, lets call it `MainComponent` receives a `JSON` input such as

```
{
   "name": "name",
   "description": "description",
   "attributes": [ // Rectangle in the image
      {
         "attr1": "value", // Editable
         "attr2": "value", // Editable
         "attr3": "value"  // Editable
      },
      {
         "attr1": "value", // Editable
         "attr2": "value", // Editable
         "attr3": "value"  // Editable
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

The important field is `attributes`. Each of its elements will be displayed as a separate area, which I'd like to code as a new component.

Each `attributes` element become a rectangle inside the main one.
And each field of an `attribute` is editable, so a `FormGroup` has to be constructed.

[image]

However, **saving** is global, not per sub-component.
And I need to take care of "listening" to which values have been modified inside each component.

I've thought about two solutions.

1. Have a `FormGroup` at the main level, with multiple sub-`FormGroup`s, one per each sub-component. Each sub-`FormGroup` is inputted inside a sub-`Component`. On save I just look at the main FormGroup, it already contains every changed value.
2. Each sub-component owns a separate `FormGroup`. On save, the main component *asks* (that is call a method) each sub-component to retrieve modified values.

Which solution is most suited to `Angular`? What would you do?

**Edit**: what I'm asking is what's the better way to distribute a `JSON` input to multiple sub-components, taking care of retrieving the edited values on save, which is at the upper/main level.

Comment: You can call a shared component and create form group with the Input attribute value ? Edit: the problem is the save button is on parent component.

Comment: @MsuArven what do you mean with *shared* component? Yes the "problem" is that one!

Comment: I think the best approach is to use `formArray`

Check this link out: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner basically inside the main component, I'd have to create a `FormGroup` which contains a `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s? Is that what you're saying? So the answer would be **option 1** (manage the state and `FormGroup` only at the main level)

Comment: Also, you need to make your `Input` component implements `ControlValueAccessor` so that you can use `formControlName` on that component.

Comment: Yes, with this way your `main` component does not need to know how many sub components there are. Each subcomponent will update `formArray` values of `formGroup` if you set it up correctly.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner each sub-component would than accept a single `FormGroup` (which comes from the `FormArray`), right?

Comment: No, they don't take any input, they just need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` so that you can use `formControlName` on them. They won't need to know about `formGroup`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner so I can just use (for example) formControlName on an input element inside a subcomponent template ? Really? I need to understand how that works

Comment: I've created a stackblitz, will post it soon

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner thank you!

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner a quick heads-up, remember each "Inputs" square above contains multiple editable values (`attr1`, `attr2`, ecc). Is it still valid to use `ControlValueAccessor`?

Comment: You can put them in a single object, can't you?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner as of now they're contained in a single object `{ "attr1": "value", "attr2": "value", ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working solution.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ugrcz)

I've used `FormArray`. For more info, read it [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays)

First, let's create an input component and call it `MyInputComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  template: `
    <div>
      Attr1: <input type="text" [ngModel]="value.attr1" 
               (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event, 'attr1')" />
    </div>
    <div>
      Attr2: <input type="text" [ngModel]="value.attr2" 
               (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event, 'attr2')" />
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyInputComponent {
  value;

  updateModel(value, attrName) {
    this.value[attrName] = value;
  }
}
```

It's a pretty simple component. It contains two inputs (you can add more) and binds a model to that input using `ngModel`. For now, it does not expose anything to outside world. On change of any of the inputs, it updates `value` accordingly.

Now, let's use it in our `main.component`

Let's say you have following data

```
  attributes = [
    { 'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value12'},
    { 'attr1': 'value2', 'attr2': 'value22'},
    { 'attr1': 'value3', 'attr2': 'value32'},
  ];
```

And, you can use this component within your template as follows

```
<div *ngFor="let attr of attributes; let i = index">
  <my-input></my-input>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Now, let's bind `formArrayName` and `formControlName` to that input.

For that, we import `ReactiveFormsModule` in our module and make `MyInput` implement `ControlValueAccessor`

`my-input.component`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  template: `
    <div>
      Attr1: <input type="text" [ngModel]="value.attr1" (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event, 'attr1')" />
    </div>
    <div>
      Attr2: <input type="text" [ngModel]="value.attr2" (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event, 'attr2')" />
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class MyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  value;

  onChange;
  onTouched;
  disabled = false;

  updateModel(value, attrName) {
    this.value[attrName] = value;
    this.onChange(this.value); // now I call onChange method to update the value within form
  }

  // comes from ControlValueAccessor
  writeValue(newValue): void {
    this.value = newValue;
  }

  // comes from ControlValueAccessor
  registerOnChange(fn: (rating: number) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // comes from ControlValueAccessor
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // comes from ControlValueAccessor
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

}
```

And change the template of main component to

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="array">
    <div *ngFor="let attr of attributes; let i = index">
      <my-input [formControlName]="i"></my-input>
      <hr />
    </div>
    <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you need to create a `formGroup` within main component as follows

```
export class AppComponent  {

  myForm = this.fb.group({
    array:  this.fb.array([])
  })

  attributes = [
    { 'attr1': 'value1', 'attr2': 'value12'},
    { 'attr1': 'value2', 'attr2': 'value22'},
    { 'attr1': 'value3', 'attr2': 'value32'},
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const arrayFormControl = this.myForm.get('array') as FormArray;
    this.attributes.forEach(attr => 
      arrayFormControl.push(this.fb.control(attr)));
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A question, inside `MyInputComponent` there is a `value` field, which is un-typed, because the interface uses `any`. Would it be a `FormGroup` in this case? (as you linked to it `[formControlName]="i"`)

Comment: Okay, it would be `FormControl`. Just read `arrayFormControl.push(this.fb.control(attr)));`

Comment: It is not `FormControl`. It is whatever value you bind. The nice thing about this is that `MyInputComponent` does not know how you use it. You can use `ngModel` instead of `[formControlName]="i"` too.

Comment: Okay! What about validation for a single attribute inside `MyInputComponent`? Wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: With this setup, you need to create some custom validation.

Comment: Or, I could still use an inner `FormGroup` (not via `Input`), similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622135/angular-controlvalueaccessor-with-inner-form-initial-value

Comment: Yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve these types of problems (data sharing). we should always create a common service. place a single `FormGroup` there. and write methods in each component to update the value of that form group. and eventually a method to get value of form group. It is by far the best method to write shared FormGroup code in services.

```
this.lotTwoFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  description: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  dutchTitle: [''],
  dutchDescription: [''],
  frenchTitle: [''],
  frenchDescription: ['']
});
```